# Get the row with minimum property value in group by using MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table (let's say, **prod_config**) with the below data-

| Prod_Id | Config_Id | Config_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9856 | 1 | 2 |
| 9855 | 93 | 1 |
| 9855 | 92 | 2 |
| 9855 | 91 | 2 |
| 9854 | 93 | 1 |
| 9854 | 92 | 2 |
| 9854 | 91 | 2 |
| 9849 | 93 | 1 |
| 9849 | 92 | 2 |
| 9850 | 91 | 2 |
| 9852 | 88 | 1 |
| 9852 | 90 | 2 |
| 9853 | 100 | 2 |

The relation is in such a way that --

- **Prod_Id** can be mapped to a single or multiple **Config_Ids (of** **Config_Type 1 or 2**)
- If **ProdId** have single occurence, then **ConfigType** will always be **2**
- If **ProdId** have multiple occurence, there will be only single row with **ConfigType** as **1**

I need to find the below result having--

- all **ProdIds** having single occurrence
- For all **ProdIds** having multiple occurrences, select only the row with **Config_Type** as 1

| Prod_Id | Config_Id | Config_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9856 | 1 | 2 |
| 9855 | 93 | 1 |
| 9854 | 93 | 1 |
| 9849 | 93 | 1 |
| 9850 | 91 | 2 |
| 9852 | 88 | 1 |
| 9853 | 100 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to get your required result -

```
SELECT Prod_Id, Config_Id, Config_Type
  FROM (SELECT Prod_Id, Config_Id, Config_Type
               COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Prod_Id) cnt_prod_id
          FROM your_table 
       )
 WHERE cnt_prod_id = 1
    OR (cnt_prod_id > 1 AND Config_Type = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one fairly easy to understand:

```
select * 
from prod_config
where prod_id in (select prod_id from prod_config
                group by prod_id
                having count(*)=1)
    or 
        (prod_id not in (select prod_id from prod_config
                        group by prod_id
                        having count(*)=1)
            and config_type=1)
;
```

But on further thought, as there can be only one config_type=1 existing for a given multiple-instance prod_id, we can simplify it to :

```
select * 
from prod_config p
where prod_id in (select prod_id from prod_config
                group by prod_id
                having count(*)=1)
    or 
         config_type=1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired output using below query

```
SELECT t1.Prod_Id, t1.Config_Id, t1.Config_Type
FROM prod_config t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM prod_config t2
    WHERE t2.Prod_Id = t1.Prod_Id AND t2.Config_Id > t1.Config_Id);
```

See demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/097789/5)